# Azure Cognitive Custom Vision

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I would like to use the training, prediction etc for my custom vision project with REST API. I do not see any place where the GET, POST methods are clearly mentioned with JSON. Is there any reference documentation?

Answer (score 7):

The training APIs are listed [here](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/d9a10a4a5f8549599f1ecafc435119fa/operations/58d5835bc8cb231380095be3).

The prediction APIs are listed [here](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/eb68250e4e954d9bae0c2650db79c653/operations/58acd3c1ef062f0344a42814).

You can download Swagger/WSDL files from those links, if that's what you prefer.

Both of those links are reachable through the [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/home) page.